# input button displaying a number on right hand corner

Tags: asp.net, html, css, css-position

Any help would be great

I'm pulling data from a database SQL

what i'm trying to do is display the result on the right hand corner of a input button.

example blow.

Any idea how i can do this?

[image]

Comment: you have problem with the sql query or the html + css?

Answer (score 0):

Here is fiddle which may help your

```
<div>
<div class="input-div">
    <input type="button" value="view"/>
    <span class="topText">value</span>
</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EeSSX/1/